# Get a property from ComboBox.SelectedItem?

Tags: vb.net, combobox, valuemember

I have a ComboBox filled with a custom Class called TableHeader, this class contains two propertys, TableName and TableText, i have set the ToString() funktion to return TableText since its what i want to display but how do i get the TableName returned?

Comment: can you post the relevant portions of TableHeader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply cast the selected item back into your TableHeader class, then use it as normal.

Make sure you only add TableHeader instances to the combobox though, otherwise the universe will explode.

Comment: Thnx alot! Ofc its done that way, i have spent about an hour trying to get my propertys out, thnx =)